# how can i get this answer + a query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table category in my database in this form

```
catID   catTitle    catParent
1       electronics     0
2       laptop          1
3       mobile          1
4       hp              2
5       hp-dv6          4
6       nokia           3
```

how can i get catID 's that are parent of hp-dv6 ?
(1,2,4,5)

thanks

---

No it didn't worked
when choosing hp-dv6 I want to get this informations:

```
catID   catTitle    catParent
1       electronics     0
2       laptop          1
4       hp              2
5       hp-dv6          4
```

---

electronics -> laptop -> hp -> hp-dv6 -> model_no ....

number of sub cats is not specified

Comment: You want to get all entries depenting on what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no recursion built in to MySQL. Instead, choices include

- joining the table to itself as often as could possibly be required
- switching to another model (e.g. [Nested Set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/))
- handling the recursion at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
SELECT * FROM category AS child 
INNER JOIN category AS parent 
ON child.catParent = parent.catID 
WHERE parent.catTitle = 'hp-dv6'
```